# Converting DDS textures to TGA

Tags: textures, dds

I have a model which has textures in DDS format, but my game takes textures in TGA format.  How can I convert the textures from DDS to TGA?

Comment: On a side note, you may not be able to produce a single `.tga` file from a `.dds`. DDS files may contain multiple image layers (*e.g.* cubemap faces), generally you would not unwrap the layers into a single TGA file because that would make re-loading the image more difficult than it needs to be. Instead, you would probably output one TGA file per-layer. Likewise, you will lose any pre-computed mipmap chain in the DDS file when you convert to TGA (you will get the highest detail mipmap level and that is it).

Comment: I found another way around. I converted the dds file into a Tga file. Then in my unix environement i went to the .FBX file and changed all the paths from .DDS to .TGA and it worked !!! :D. Anyway thank you very much for you help :) hope this way helps somebody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert .dds to .tga with a variety of tools, such as

- the command-line [NVIDIA texture tools](https://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/),
- the [NVIDIA Photoshop plugins](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-adobe-photoshop) if you have Photoshop, or
- the [image editor built into recent Visual Studio versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315744.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tools NathanReed mentioned, ImageMagick can now also do this.

It supports more source (and target) formats than the NVidia texture tools, which is quite convenient, and allows performing lots of image operations during conversion (like flipping, scaling to powers of two etc).
http://www.imagemagick.org

Example:

```
convert -flip foo.png foo.dds
```